# PIG - Implement COGROUP using Pig Latin

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, apache-pig

I would like to know if it is possible to imitate the result of COGROUP by using basic PIG LATIN statements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#cogroup

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "imitate the result of COGROUP" ?

Pig Latin language already has a function for [COGROUP](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#cogroup).

Example:

```
COGROUP alias BY (col1, col2)
```

COGROUP is usually used when multiple relations are involved.

Comment: Yes. I do know that. Is there a way to its functionality?

Comment: @Maddy What do you mean?

Comment: I would like to imitate its function. I know that we can use the COGROUP command, but I would like to use a list of primitive PIG script lines to imitate it. For example, we can imitate JOIN function using COGROUP by :

1. Using COGROUP between the two relations on a common key.
2. Flattening the required fields to imitate the result.

Is there any way to imitate the COGROUP using any other command in PIG?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you need to do this? The following code works for 2 alias

```
>cat test1
1,aaaa
2,bbbb
3,cccc
4,dddd
5,eeee
6,ffff
7,gggg
8,hhhh
9,iiii

>cat test2
7,ggggggg
8,hhhhhhh
9,iiiiiii
10,jjjjjjj
11,kkkkkkk
7,9999
7,gggg

grunt>test1 = load 'test1' USING PigStorage(',') as (id: int, val: chararray);
grunt>test2 = load 'test2' USING PigStorage(',') as (id: int, val: chararray);
grunt>cgrp = cogroup test1 by id, test2 by id;
grunt>dump cgrp;
```

we have

```
(1,{(1,aaaa)},{})
(2,{(2,bbbb)},{})
(3,{(3,cccc)},{})
(4,{(4,dddd)},{})
(5,{(5,eeee)},{})
(6,{(6,ffff)},{})
(7,{(7,gggg)},{(7,ggggggg),(7,9999),(7,gggg)})
(8,{(8,hhhh)},{(8,hhhhhhh)})
(9,{(9,iiii)},{(9,iiiiiii)})
(10,{},{(10,jjjjjjj)})
(11,{},{(11,kkkkkkk)})
```

The following code can give the same result

```
grunt>g1 = group test1 by id;
grunt>g2 = group test2 by id;
grunt>j = join g1 by group FULL, g2 by group;
grunt>j2 = foreach j generate (g1::group is null ? g2::group : g1::group), (test1 is null? (bag{tuple(int, chararray)}){} : test1) as test1, (test2 is null? (bag{tuple(int,chararray)}){} : test2) as test2;
```